Explanation math expression to form a cluster
Could someone please explain to me, in simple terms, the mathematical expression from the paper "Ammar, H.A., Adve, R., Shahbazpanahi, S., Boudreau, G., and Srinivas, K.V., 2021. Distributed resource allocation optimization for user-centric cell-free MIMO networks. IEEE Transactions on Wireless Communications, 21(5), pp.3099-3115."
The specific expression I’m referring to is highlighted in the attached screenshot:

I’m not very strong in math, and I’ve spent a lot of time trying to understand it without success. I would greatly appreciate any help or a simple explanation to make sense of it.
Thank you in advance!
Other screenshots of System model description:


OK, usually you'd formulate it as in the second formula,

$$\{ \psi_{ru}\,\beta(d_{ru}) \ge \rho: r\in \mathcal B\}$$

would more succinctly be written as

$$\{ r | \psi_{ru}\,\beta(d_{ru}) \ge \rho\}$$

This is the set of DUs that meet the following criterion:
The product of path "loss" (more a "gain") (which depends on the distance from the user to the DU) and the shadowing (which is random drawn from a lognormal distribution) must be at least some threshold $\rho$. In other words, the signal power loss between DU and user must not be worse than $\rho$.

I’m not very strong in math

You're doing well! You're operating in a very math-heavy domain, and catching up on basics of notation is something best done at the beginning of studying of a domain. So, asking about things when you're confused is a good way forward.
As a recommendation: when you meet a term like that, make sure you first identify all syntax elements you know to make sure you are clear whether you generally understand the statement. Then, identify whether you can map the used variable symbols to meanings as defined in the text you're reading.
This two step process,

make 100% sure you understand the syntax of a formula,
"hunt down" the symbols used in the formula

is what I use all the time when facing new formulas in literature. The cognitive step of just understanding why you don't understand a formula is critical, and usually allows one to figure out the meaning of the syntax yourself.

What can the 'p' threshold be? Is it related to network conditions or data rate? Do I understand correctly that the threshold serves as a limit for the product of gain and shadowing?

@Aid22 "What can the 'p' threshold be" that's a $\rho$ (Greek letter rho), not a "p" :-) however, I can't tell you the meaning of a symbols not defined in the text you showed. Generally, it's some real number, because it's used together with the $>$ operator.

@Aid22 "Do I understand correctly that the threshold serves as a limit for the product of gain and shadowing?" Having to ask that after reading the formula AND my answer: are you sure you understand the set notation ${ … | …}$? If not, you need to work on that first. You can't get through this paper without math basics, and I'm sure you had that much math, you just need to refresh that.
